# How to add a user to a SharePoint user group

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have a contacts list that I would like the ability to add a contact (user) to the Visitor's security group.  I have a workflow that gets the appropriate security group and now I need a HTTP REST request of adding this user to that group.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to add a user to a group using SharePoint Rest API. If so, you can take a reference of below dcos:

- [POST request example: Add a user to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)#usercollection-resource)

[image]

- https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/add-user-to-site-group-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api

BR

Comment: My problem is transferring this example into the SharePoint workflow equivalent.  i understand my endpoint is:                                                                                                     
 "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups(7)/users
    ?@target='<app web url>'"                             and how to define my headers dictionary entry.  I can't figure out the rest.

Comment: OK, i see. You want to add a "Call HTTP Web Service" action in your workflow, right? if so, please take a reference of this 2 blogs: https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/rest-api-post-call-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow#the-step-by-step-process-of-creating-a-designer-workflow-using-rest-api-post-method

Comment: And this blog: http://codelesssharepointinfopath.com/workflow-useful-rest-calls-add-user-to-group/

Comment: Ok, I got it working, but not completely.  I keep getting Unauthorized as my response.  I have full control on the site.  I also added it in an app Step.  My loginname I'm adding is i:0#.f|wiextmember|ssharvancik.  I can add this person manually though.

Comment: Could you please have a try elevated permissions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I did (aka app Step).  That's why I'm confused.

Comment: What is another reason that I do not have authorization?

Comment: My parameters: {"__metadata":{"Type":"SP.User"},"LoginName":"i:0#.w|dhs\\harvass"}  My URL: [%Workflow Context: Current Site URL%]/sitegroups/GetByName('MES Visitors')/users

Comment: I am a site collection administrator for this site and I still get unauthorized response.